# Cannot login with custom loginProcessingUrl

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm building a REST service with Spring and using Spring Security. The default solution with loginform doesn't pass for me. Here it's my WebSecurityConfig:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 class PostAuthSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(200);
        }

    }
    class PostAuthFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(403);
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(httpServletResponse.getOutputStream()));
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    private MySQLUserDetailsManager mySQLUserDetailsManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/registration", "/checkUser", "/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .successHandler(new PostAuthSuccessHandler())
            .failureHandler(new PostAuthFailureHandler())
            .permitAll()
        .and().logout()
            .permitAll()
        .and().exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/scripts/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/styles/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/jquery-validate/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/bootstrap-3.3.6/**");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(mySQLUserDetailsManager);
    }
}
```

But /login request is always 403 forbidden. I'm understanding, that something redirect me to /error. 
**UPD:** All pages are responding 403 Forbidden, even "/","/checkuser".

Answer (score 0):

I forget, that in standard form there is a csrf key in hidden input. So:

```
http
    .csrf().disable()
```